# Global pointer to object causes access violation?

Tags: c++

Maybe you will be able to clear something for me, because I don't know exactly where my thinking is flawed. First some code:

Talker.h:

```
class talker       
{
    public:
    talker();
    void sayHello() {cout << "Hello";} ;
};
```

anotherClass.h:

```
class anotherClass
{
    public:
    anotherClass();
    void doSomethingYourself() { cout << "will do"; };
    void askHimToSayHello() { pointerToTalker->sayHello; };  
                          //Access violation, bad pointer(?)
};
```

common.h:

```
 static talker *pointerToTalker;       
      // if I add here "= new talker", code works fine
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "common.h"
int main()
{
    pointerToTalker = new talker;            // Here is the bug, but why?
    pointerToTalker -> sayHello;             // says Hello alright

    anotherClass *pointerToAnotherClass = new anotherClass;
    pointerToAnotherClass -> doSomething ();  //Does something OK

    pointerToAnotherClass -> askHimToSayHello(); // Causes access violation 
}
```

Of course functions are a bit more complex, and each is implemeted in coresponding .cpp including "common.h". My question is - why pointerToTalker, if initialized inside main() does not work inside anotherClass::AskHimToSayHello()? It should pointing to valid memory by the time it is used there.
It is my "Hello world, OOP!" btw, so please be gentle if there is no hope for me :)

Sorry for the childish style btw. It helps me cut down the code I have to something more compact without me loosing the big picture :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because

```
static talker *pointerToTalker;
```

is not a global. In this context, `static` gives the variable internal linkage for each translation unit (cpp file + included files) in which `common.h` is included.

You need to declare it as `extern`:

```
extern talker *pointerToTalker;
```

and initialize it in a single implementation file.

Declaring it `static` will create a copy of `pointerToTalker` for each translation unit. So you're initializing the one from `main.cpp`. Others are left uninitialized, and thus you run into **undefined behavior**. The proper way is:

```
//common.h:
extern talker *pointerToTalker;    

//common.cpp
#include "common.h"
talker* pointerToTalker = new talker;
```